# Css Select Box On IE 5 & IE 11

Tags: html, css, internet-explorer-11

I have a select box with code:

```
<html:select property="list_data" size="12" style="width: 350px;" ondblclick="JavaScript:doOK()">
    <html:optionsCollection property="list_data" label="codeAndNameLabel" value="codeAndName" />
</html:select>
```

When run it on IE 11 & IE 5 then layout difference about border & box-shadow. How change css to layout on IE 5 is same with IE 11.

Thanks very much!

Comment: IE 5 is incredibly outdated. Why are you even trying to make the site look the same in IE 5 and IE 11? For many modern layouts and interactions, that may not even be possible.

Comment: thanks about your answer @Ed Cottrell. I only want know does it have solution ^^

Answer (score 0):

Box-shadow is only available in IE 9 and later. ([Source](http://caniuse.com/#feat=css-boxshadow)) In old versions of IE, you have to do either image borders or some sort of fancy overlaying of elements; you can't use modern CSS.

That said, you are almost certainly looking at this the wrong way. You should not spend huge amounts of effort on very old browsers. [IE 5 dates from *1999*, for crying out loud](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Internet_Explorer_5). Instead, go for progressive enhancement (the old browsers work, but newer browsers support more features) or graceful degradation (older browsers display a version with reduced functionality or a warning, rather than breaking entirely). [Here's a good article from the W3C on these topics](https://www.w3.org/wiki/Graceful_degradation_versus_progressive_enhancement).

At the end of the day, it sounds like you have the [XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/66377/238426). The problem is not "how do I make IE 5 do XYZ," but "do I need to support IE 5 and, if so, is it worth a huge amount of effort to make IE 5 look like a modern browser?" The answer is almost certainly, "No." Seriously, IE 5 accounts for a fraction of 1% of all traffic; it's not even in the top 40 at this point. See, for example, [Net Market Share's stats](https://www.netmarketshare.com/browser-market-share.aspx?qprid=2&qpcustomd=0). (No affiliation.)